# Grouping column indices of an array based on max value of another list in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have an array

```
k= array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
          [2, 5, 4, 7, 3],
          [4, 7, 6, 8, 2],
          [1, 2, 4, 3, 6],
          [7, 8, 9, 5, 4]])
```

Assuming that after computing for each columns in an array I got `array([0.6,0.4,0.75,0.2,0.75])` respectively, such that:

computation on column1 i.e. computation on `array([1,5,2,4,1,7])` results in 0.6,
computation on column2 i.e. computation on `array([2,6,5,7,2,8])` results in 0.4,
computation on column3 i.e. computation on `array([3,7,4,6,4,9])` results in 0.75, and so on.

Let the computed list be m. such that

`m=array([0.6,0.4,0.75,0.2,0.75])`

So far I have computed for single columns in array `k`. Now I would like to group the elements in list `m` based on the largest floating point element in the list `m` and compute again on k. For example:

`m[2]=m[4]=0.75` (largest number in the array),  that would mean index 2 and index 4 of column in array `k` is largest. So keeping that index number common I would like to group `k[:,2] with k[:,0],k[:,2] with k[:,1],k[:,2] with k[:,3] and similarly k[:,4] with k[:,0],k[:,4] with k[:,1],k[:,4] with k[:,3]` and compute again on `k`,

such that grouping `k[:,2] with k[:,0]` means :

```
k0_2=array([[1,3],          k1_2=array([[2,3],          k3_2=array([[4,3],
            [5,7],                      [6,7],                      [8,7],
            [2,4],                      [5,4],                      [7,4],
            [4,6],                      [7,6],                      [8,6],
            [1,4],                      [2,4],                      [3,4],  
            [7,9]])                     [8,9]])                     [5,9]])

k0_4=array([[1,5],          k1_4=array([[2,5],          k3_4=array([[4,5],
            [5,9],                      [6,9],                      [8,9],
            [2,9],                      [5,3],                      [7,3],
            [4,2],                      [7,2],                      [8,2],
            [1,6],                      [2,6],                      [3,6],  
            [7,4]])                     [8,4]])                     [5,4]])
```

Can anyone please give me any clue regarding grouping column indices of `array k` based on max value of `list m` as shown above .

Comment: I don't quite understand your paragraph with the sentence "So keeping that index number common...". What do you mean by "compute again on `k`"? And how do you get the groups you've described in that sentence? Could you make this a bit clearer, for example describe to us in more details the steps we would take to get these groups?

Comment: By saying i would like to keep the index number common i meant that all I want to keep the index number of greater element in the list M common and use that index, to group with non max index as shown above.

Comment: I am trying to understand what the paragraph I mentioned means and how you work out this grouping. If that means you also need to explain how you got the array `m` then sure.

Comment: Based on lower approximation i got m. You will get good enough literature on that topic.

Comment: Your question has a lot of irrelevant detail but doesn't specify what you actually want. What does the required answer look like?  Do you want a list of 6-by-2 arrays?  If so, what order should they come in?  If not, what is the form of the answer?

Comment: Sorry if I could not clarify my doubts. all i need is k0_2,k1_2,k0_2,k3_2 and k0_4,k1_4,k3_4 as shown above.

Comment: k0_2 = k[:, [0,2]] for example.  Is that all you needed to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
import numpy as np

k= np.array(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     [2, 5, 4, 7, 3],
     [4, 7, 6, 8, 2],
     [1, 2, 4, 3, 6],
     [7, 8, 9, 5, 4]])

cols=[2,4]
others = [c for c in range(k.shape[1]) if c not in cols]
groups = [k[:,[o, c]] for c in cols for o in others]
for g in groups:
    print(g)
    print('')
```

This gives me

```
[[1 3]
 [5 7]
 [2 4]
 [4 6]
 [1 4]
 [7 9]]

[[2 3]
 [6 7]
 [5 4]
 [7 6]
 [2 4]
 [8 9]]

[[4 3]
 [8 7]
 [7 4]
 [8 6]
 [3 4]
 [5 9]]

[[1 5]
 [5 9]
 [2 3]
 [4 2]
 [1 6]
 [7 4]]

[[2 5]
 [6 9]
 [5 3]
 [7 2]
 [2 6]
 [8 4]]

[[4 5]
 [8 9]
 [7 3]
 [8 2]
 [3 6]
 [5 4]]
```

I think there's a typographical error in your k_04 array.  I think k_04[2,10 should be 3, not 9, isn't that so?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) and yeah my mistake. It's an error anyway thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which I along with one of my friend figured it out :

```
import numpy as np

k= np.array(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
     [2, 5, 4, 7, 3],
     [4, 7, 6, 8, 2],
     [1, 2, 4, 3, 6],
     [7, 8, 9, 5, 4]])

cols=[2,4]
kl = np.delete(k, np.s_[cols],1)

 for i in range(len(cols)):
     for j in range(len(kl[0])):
          print np.column_stack((k[:,cols[i]],kl[:,j]))
```